# watch requests between db server and client

Tags: mysql

Is there any tool which can monitor the requests and responses between a MySQL server and clients? Basically I want to know how many requests my web app makes to the mysql server and analyze the performance.

Is there any similar thing available for MSSQL server also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bash script to monitor MySQL requests: http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/monitoring-mysql-queries-using-bash-script/ And here is web-based variant of monitor: http://webyog.com/en/ (check out MONyog screenshots to understand is it really what you need).

Answer (score 0):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/m/mysql.html) will do the trick.  Wireshark is a general purpose protocol analyser and includes fitlers for a variety of applications including Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it myself, but [MySQL proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy) should do what you want.